# Clear UIView's BackGround Color on Touch With Finger

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview, uigraphicscontext

I make an Image Editing App. So I want to fill the color of uiview by user and the user erase the color with finger touch.
I write this code for the UIImageView clear with finger but how to clear uiview color.

**I want to make like PicsArt's Paper Effect.(PicsArt on App store)**
please help me...

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    lastTouch = [touch locationInView:_imageview];}
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    CGPoint currentTouch = [touch locationInView:_imageview];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(_imageview.frame.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [_imageview.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, _imageview.frame.size.width, _imageview.frame.size.width)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
   CGContextSetLineWidth(context,10);
   CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeClear);
   CGContextBeginPath(context);
   CGContextMoveToPoint(context, lastTouch.x, lastTouch.y);
   CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, currentTouch.x, currentTouch.y);
   CGContextStrokePath(context);
  _imageview.image= UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  lastTouch = [touch locationInView:_imageview];}
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{


 UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint currentTouch = [touch locationInView:_imageview];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(_imageview.frame.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[_imageview.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, _imageview.frame.size.width, _imageview.frame.size.width)];
CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context,10);
CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeClear);
CGContextBeginPath(context);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, lastTouch.x, lastTouch.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, currentTouch.x, currentTouch.y);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
_imageview.image= UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

lastTouch = [touch locationInView:_imageview];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
    - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    lastTouch = [touch locationInView:_imageview];}
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    CGPoint currentTouch = [touch locationInView:_imageview];


    lastTouch = [touch locationInView:_imageview];
    //redraw the view
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{


    lastTouch = [touch locationInView:_imageview];
    //redraw your view
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
//Put your draw code here;

//    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(_imageview.frame.size);
//    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
//    [_imageview.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, _imageview.frame.size.width, _imageview.frame.size.width)];
//    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
//    CGContextSetLineWidth(context,10);
//    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeClear);
//    CGContextBeginPath(context);
//    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, lastTouch.x, lastTouch.y);
//    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, currentTouch.x, currentTouch.y);
//    CGContextStrokePath(context);
//    _imageview.image= UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
//    
//    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

@Milan patel. An copy of you code with some updates.

Comment: [[UIColor clearColor]setFill];
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

Comment: Before you continue to code, you can refer to Quartz 2D Programming Guide, which can help you understand the drawing system. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: You understand what is my question actually or not I want to create Paper Effect like PicsArt App..